# How can I build up an ActiveRecord query with optional parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I was wondering, how can I have multiple where conditions depending on whether I have a parameter or not?

The following approach is not working, which makes sense:

```
scope :within_distance, ->(point, radius=10000, _supplier=nil) {
  joins(:address)
  unless _supplier.nil?
    .where(:supplier => _supplier)
  end
  .where("ST_DWithin(lonlat,'#{point.as_text}'::geography ,#{radius},true)")
  .order("ST_Distance(lonlat, ST_GeomFromText('#{point.as_text}', #{SRID}))")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you were trying to do, but in valid Ruby. Use a local variable to build up the query.

```
scope :within_distance, ->(point, radius=10000, _supplier=nil) {
  query = joins(:address)
  unless _supplier.nil?
    query = query.where(:supplier => _supplier)
  end
  query.where("ST_DWithin(lonlat,'#{point.as_text}'::geography ,#{radius},true)")
    .order("ST_Distance(lonlat, ST_GeomFromText('#{point.as_text}', #{SRID}))")
}
```